# Match words separated by single spaces, with no spaces at start or end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm aiming to create a regex that allows alphanumerics and any special characters.

```
Example of accepted words:
Test 1
Test 123 !#@#
```

But it shouldn't accept characters that have spaces before or after the word, or also multiple spaces, or only whitespace.

```
Example of unaccepted words:
 Test 1   - spaces before
Test   1   - multiple spaces between
Test(spaces) - spaces after
(only spaces) - only spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a regexp, you can `split` the string on spaces, then use `every` to make sure there are no null strings in the result (which would mean that there were extra spaces either at the beginning or end or in between words somewhere).

```js
const tests = ['Test 1', ' Test 1', 'Test 123 !#@#', 'Test   1', 'Test  ', '   '];

const passes = str => str . split(' ') . every(Boolean);

document.getElementById('results').textContent = 
  tests.map(str => `'${str}': ${passes(str)}`) . join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="results" style="white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; "></div>
```

How does this `every(Boolean)` work? It converts each element to a boolean true/false value, and makes sure that they all convert to true. In JS, an empty string will convert to false, so this checks that each element is **not** an empty string.

Comment: what if there is one space before the word?

Comment: As you will see if you try it, that will result in an initial empty string in the result from `split`, which will cause the `every` to fail.

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
^[^ ]+( [^ ])*$
```

Please escape the special characters accordingly to the language you will use for your regex.

Comment: You can use `\S` for `[^ ]`.

Comment: @torazaburo Beware though, the question was asking about whitespace. `\S` will also match tabulations and line jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
^[^ ]+( \S+)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`^[\w]+( [\w]+)*$`